# SharePoint 2016 Error 404 SOS

Tags: error, 2016, 404

Using SharePoint 2016, after install update KB3203432 and reboot server. SharePoint site shows error 404.

When I try access to site collection/sites, I get 404 error

When i try access to site collection/sites/page it returns "Permission is required to access this item".

---

I don't know what blog to watch.(Beginner)

```
06.11.2017 10:56:34.28  wsstracing.exe (0x0C9C) 0x3BD4  SharePoint Foundation   Unified Logging Service b9wt    High    Log retention limit reached.  Log file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS\SP16-20170528-1006.log' has been deleted.  
06.11.2017 10:56:34.28  wsstracing.exe (0x0C9C) 0x3BD4  SharePoint Foundation   Tracing Controller Service  8096    Information Usage log retention limit reached.  Some old usage log files have been deleted. 
06.11.2017 10:56:59.62  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x5200  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope: (Updating dependency collection file cache.) Время выполнения=170.623221666441; CPU Milliseconds=22; Число запросов SQL=62; Parent=Invalidating object collection file cache according to change type  4c85fa9d-4daa-2071-d0a7-a40ece700cf9
06.11.2017 10:56:59.62  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x5200  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    High    ____Число запросов SQL=62   4c85fa9d-4daa-2071-d0a7-a40ece700cf9
06.11.2017 10:56:59.62  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x5200  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    High    ____Время выполнения=170.623221666441   4c85fa9d-4daa-2071-d0a7-a40ece700cf9
06.11.2017 10:56:59.68  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x5200  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope: (Invalidating object collection file cache according to change type) Время выполнения=232.707369232682; CPU Milliseconds=82; Число запросов SQL=63; Parent=Timer Job Health Statistics Updating    4c85fa9d-4daa-2071-d0a7-a40ece700cf9
06.11.2017 10:56:59.68  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x5200  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    High    ____Число запросов SQL=63   4c85fa9d-4daa-2071-d0a7-a40ece700cf9
06.11.2017 10:56:59.68  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x5200  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  arm3c   High    ____CPU Milliseconds=82 4c85fa9d-4daa-2071-d0a7-a40ece700cf9
06.11.2017 10:56:59.68  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x5200  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    High    ____Время выполнения=232.707369232682   4c85fa9d-4daa-2071-d0a7-a40ece700cf9
06.11.2017 10:56:59.68  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x5200  SharePoint Foundation   General a2o4g   Unexpected  SPLoggingLock held lock for 234 milliseconds. Call stack: (not slow enough  for stack trace)    4c85fa9d-4daa-2071-d0a7-a40ece700cf9
06.11.2017 10:57:00.67  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x6114  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope: (Refreshing object collection file cache.) Время выполнения=241.500805269944; CPU Milliseconds=40; Число запросов SQL=74; Parent=None  68c9212d-de49-44bb-b2b1-652357031340
06.11.2017 10:57:00.67  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x6114  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    High    ____Число запросов SQL=74   68c9212d-de49-44bb-b2b1-652357031340
06.11.2017 10:57:00.67  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x6114  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    High    ____Время выполнения=241.500805269944   68c9212d-de49-44bb-b2b1-652357031340
06.11.2017 10:57:01.50  w3wp.exe (0x24CC)   0x295C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope: (Firing DelayedFileSystemWatcher notifications) Время выполнения=11.1370998269333; CPU Milliseconds=4; Число запросов SQL=3; Parent=None   
06.11.2017 10:57:01.50  w3wp.exe (0x24CC)   0x295C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    High    ____Число запросов SQL=3    
06.11.2017 10:57:07.99  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x61E0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope: (Updating dependency collection file cache.) Время выполнения=170.665196274946; CPU Milliseconds=21; Число запросов SQL=62; Parent=Invalidating object collection file cache according to change type  
06.11.2017 10:57:07.99  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x61E0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    High    ____Число запросов SQL=62   
06.11.2017 10:57:07.99  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x61E0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    High    ____Время выполнения=170.665196274946   
06.11.2017 10:57:07.99  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x61E0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope: (Invalidating object collection file cache according to change type) Время выполнения=172.37470125393; CPU Milliseconds=22; Число запросов SQL=63; Parent=Firing DelayedFileSystemWatcher notifications    
06.11.2017 10:57:07.99  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x61E0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    High    ____Число запросов SQL=63   
06.11.2017 10:57:07.99  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x61E0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    High    ____Время выполнения=172.37470125393    
06.11.2017 10:57:07.99  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x61E0  SharePoint Foundation   General a2o4g   Unexpected  SPLoggingLock held lock for 172 milliseconds. Call stack: (not slow enough  for stack trace)    
06.11.2017 10:57:07.99  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x61E0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope: (Firing DelayedFileSystemWatcher notifications) Время выполнения=177.028365336935; CPU Milliseconds=26; Число запросов SQL=64; Parent=None 
06.11.2017 10:57:07.99  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x61E0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    High    ____Число запросов SQL=64   
06.11.2017 10:57:07.99  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x61E0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    High    ____Время выполнения=177.028365336935   
06.11.2017 10:57:10.99  w3wp.exe (0x7D48)   0x7B40  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope: (Firing DelayedFileSystemWatcher notifications) Время выполнения=14.6051383625573; CPU Milliseconds=4; Число запросов SQL=5; Parent=None   
06.11.2017 10:57:10.99  w3wp.exe (0x7D48)   0x7B40  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    High    ____Число запросов SQL=5    
06.11.2017 10:57:14.01  vssphost5.exe (0x4C54)  0x4EA0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope: (Firing DelayedFileSystemWatcher notifications) Время выполнения=11.3125411190528; CPU Milliseconds=3; Число запросов SQL=4; Parent=None   
06.11.2017 10:57:14.01  vssphost5.exe (0x4C54)  0x4EA0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    High    ____Число запросов SQL=4    
06.11.2017 10:57:18.45  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x610C  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  dkd5    High    synchronizing search service instance   5185fa9d-4d4f-2071-d0a7-a51913fae7c4
06.11.2017 10:57:18.45  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x6104)   0x610C  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  eff0    High    synchronizing search data access service instance   5185fa9d-4d4f-2071-d0a7-a51913fae7c4
```

Comment: Can you please the ULS?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to check.

- As Per Requirement, Did you install updates on all SharePoint servers? Most important, Did you run SharePoint config wizard on all server in farm.(must have)
- Check Central Admin Site and make sure all the content databases attach to SharePoint.
- Also review the database status and make no one is saying upgrade required.